# jquery .load not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

working on .load() to keep on updating some data from a database.

This is for a test website im learning on.

So I have a basic structure like:

```
<div id="playerlist">Player 1, Player 2</div>
```

And then I have tried this:

```
  function pageUpdate(){
    $('#playerlist').load("test.php");
  }
  setTimeout(pageUpdate, 10000);
```

The test.php is in the same folder as the page its being called on, and to test it the content of the page is:

```
Hello!
```

But nothing is happening, no errors or anything... any help where I am going wrong?

Craig

Comment: Did you included jquery to your html page?

Comment: @user2921557 look at Firebug -> Console tab, if `load` is working you should see ajax request in it..

Comment: Yes, using Bootstrap and changed the jQuery link to the latest as well.

Comment: Nothing is showing in the console tab neither. All seems a bit odd. Ill have a look into the jQuery link and make sure its all working okay.

Comment: See what is the load function returning

Comment: Not even being called I don't think. The function and timeout is working fine, If put an alert in the function it shows, but the load doesn't seem to be calling...